# How to define an extension function for a companion object of a typealias?

Tags: kotlin

I thought typealiases were the same as the original type, just a different name.

I figure typealiases have the same references as the original type.

```
typealias Celsius = Double

fun Double.Companion.foo() {} // Works
fun Celsius.Companion.foo() {} // Does not work
```

Here, `Companion` is accessible from `Double` but `Celsius` gives an unresolved reference error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't access to the companion objects via typealias. One possible workaround to create one more typealias for concrete companion:

```
typealias CelsiusCompanion = Double.Companion
```

After that you can use it as following:

```
fun CelsiusCompanion.foo() {}
```

Comment: please do you happen to know why Kotlin doesn't support that? Is there a feature request? It breaks backwards compatibility when renaming classes, but providing a typealias.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define an extension function, it is not possible as hluhovskyi already stated, but things are differently if you just want to invoke functions of a `companion object`.

There are two ways of accessing functions and properties within a `companion object`. You can either specify the access explicitely or implicitely. The implicit way works with a `typealias` the explicit one does not.

Consider this minimal example:

```
class ClassWithCompanion{
    companion object {
        fun sayHello() {
            println("Hello")
        }
    } 
}

typealias Alias = ClassWithCompanion

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    ClassWithCompanion.sayHello() // implicit
    ClassWithCompanion.Companion.sayHello() // explicit 

    Alias.sayHello() // implicit (works)
    Alias.Companion.test() // explicit (does not work)
}
```